# How can I replace iWay, as a SAP adapter, from homegrown Java application

Tags: java, adapter, sapjco3

How can I replace iWay, as a SAP adapter, from  a homegrown Java application?

I have sapjco3.jar and libsapjco3.so with me.

Can I get any documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAP Java Connector is closed source and available for free, but only for SAP customers and partners.

If you have a SAP Service Marketplace account, you can get the JCo SDK from here:
https://service.sap.com/connectors.

The downloadable SDK archive also contains the JavaDoc and some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple of links for you.

[JCO Tutorial Part 1 - Direct JCO Connection](http://www.apentia-forum.de/viewtopic.php?t=1962)

and

[JCO JavaDocs](https://help.sap.com/javadocs/NW04S/current/jc/index.html)

Comment: Your links refer to the old outdated JCo 2.x. The question was about the current JCo version 3.0 which has a different API.